# Extra argument 'username' in call - WatsonCloud SpeechToTextV1

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to implement WatsonCloud in my project, however I am encountering the following error:

> `Extra argument 'username' in call`

Here is the code below from the documentation

```
let speechToText = SpeechToText(username: "XX", password: "XX")
```

But it's not actually working when using it inside a project with the SpeechToTextV1 Framework.

Comment: From the source in GitHub an API key is expected: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/blob/master/Source/SpeechToTextV1/README.md

Answer (score 0):

SpeechtoText accepts only one argument which is authenticator. It can be created using *WatsonBasicAuthenticator*. You can check from this link:
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=swift#authentication